# Geometry problem of square.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> $ABCD$ is a square with $X$ and $Y$ as midpoints of $BC$ and $CD$
> respectively. $Z$ is a point inside $ABCD$ such that $XZ = XY$ and $CZ
> > = 3AZ$. Find the ratio of the areas of triangles $CXY$ and $XZY$.

I was not able to solve this problem so then I looked for the solution provided and there it was mentioned as part of the solution that

> As $XZ = XY$, Z lies on the diagonal AC.

And I am not able to understand how can deduce the above statement which is provided in the solution. Please help!!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Suspecting a typo somewhere. $Z$ on $AC$ would be implied by $XZ=\color{red}{Z}Y$, not by $XZ=XY$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop : I re-checked and it's the same i.e. $=$.

Comment: I am implying that there would be a typo in either the problem or in the solution or in both. Not all math books are free of errors.

Comment: There is indeed a typo. At first I assumed that there's not a typo and calculated, the I discovered that $CZ<3AZ$ is always true, i.e, $CZ$ cannot be greater or equal to $3AZ$ if $XZ=XY$.